# handover ConsoleColor to method in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to write a short method that I can use to write one single line in the console colorful.

Currently I have to call my method like this:

```
ChangeConsoleColor("ABC", ConsoleColor.Yellow, ConsoleColor.Red);
```

But I want to be able to call it like this:

```
ChangeConsoleColor("ABC", Yellow, Red);
```

The perfectly working code I have looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myText = "ABCDEFG";
    ChangeConsoleColor(myText, ConsoleColor.Yellow, ConsoleColor.Red);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
}

private static void ChangeConsoleColor(string Text, ConsoleColor BGC, ConsoleColor FGC)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = BGC;
    Console.ForegroundColor = FGC;
    Console.WriteLine(Text);
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

How do I need to change my code to get rid of the 'ConsoleColor' in the function call part?

Comment: `using static System.ConsoleColor;`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier

Comment: Sight, sometimes the answer can be soooo obvious. Thanks for opening my eyes for it.

Comment: The `using static` construct was introduced in C# v6 (in the VS 2015 timeframe) with little fanfare.  It was easy to miss.